# How do I post custom stories directly to the user's Facebook wall in Android SDK 4.0?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having a problem getting my custom story to post directly to the person's wall without using the Share Dialog and have been unable to find examples or proper documentation on how to do anything like this in the new SDK (much of the documentation on Graph API on Facebook's site seems to be outdated...) The person is already logged in to Facebook at this point, has given permission for the app to post, and has clicked a button to share the story of them using the app to perform a social action.

Currently, my code manages to make and execute a `GraphRequest` containing the information about the object and the action, which returns to it's callback with no error, and gives a response with a return code of 200(OK), and an 'id' number in it, which I would think indicates a successful post, but the story is not getting onto the wall.

I also see that the object which I sent in the request has been created when I go to the Facebook Developer site and look in the Object Browser for my app... All the details I sent in the request are showing up there correctly... I'm sure I posted the request to the right graph path for my action, my `AccessToken` is valid, the app has the proper `publish_actions` permission, I'm pretty sure I gave the parameters the action is expecting, (at least, the object parameter seems to be valid and using the right name for its key, since the object posted and I didn't get the error back about missing the `my_object` parameter...)

This is my code (namespace, object and action names are changed, but it should make no difference for the problem at hand):

```
// Create object
JSONObject myObject=new JSONObject();
try {
    myObject.put("og:type", "my_namespace:my_object");
    myObject.put("og:title", facebookStoryTitle);
    myObject.put("og:description", facebookStoryDescription);
    myObject.put("place:location:latitude", facebookPlaceLat);
    myObject.put("place:location:longitude", facebookPlaceLon);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    String toastText = "JSON Error: " + e.getMessage();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toastText, 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}

// Create action
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putInt("expires_in", facebookStoryExpires);
params.putString("my_object", myObject.toString());

// Create request
GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), 
    "me/my_namespace:my_action", params, HttpMethod.POST, 
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

        FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
        if (error != null) {
            // Display User Error Message
            String toastText = error.getErrorUserMessage(); 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toastText,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;             
        } else {
            // DEBUG: Display Response
            String toastText = response.toString(); 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toastText,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;                                 
        }
    }
});

// Send Request
request.executeAsync();
```

Comment: If you're getting back a 200 response, that means the post was created successfully but that doesn't mean it has to be shown in the timeline. Facebook users can change their privacy settings, you can enable the option to review all the post that go to your timeline and until you approve them, they won't show up. The post will show up at the user's activity log section but not at the timeline. That's just an example, there are different privacy settings a user can enable in order to avoid the behaviour you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, but the user I am posting to is myself and I have given the app full permissions to post publicly, I approved it from the Facebook Login when it requested the publish_actions permission... I am not seeing the posts in any review queue or anything like that... It has the proper access token, (MY access token from my login, not an app access token), AND the app settings are set on my account so that posts from this app are public... Also, when I use the simplified code in the documentation which brings up the share dialog, it posts just fine, and everyone can see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give 
`params.putString("fb:explicitly_shared", true);`
 to show the post in timeline.

Comment: Quick question about the `fb:explicitly_shared`. How do I ask Facebook for that permission? I just can't find it anywhere on the facebook-developer-dashboard for my app.